# How can refresh or restart MediaStore after adding or deleting or any modifying files on the SDcard?

Tags: android, refresh, mediastore

I have a public question.In android ,How can refresh or restart MediaStore after adding or deleting or any modifying files on the SDcard?
I can call this after my modinfing on SDcard but i dont like use this.becuse may be exists another better ways.any help appreciate me.

```
sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED, Uri.parse("file://"+ Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I find response for my post.
i use this method after deleting or adding or any midifying on sdcard.

```
static void scanWithPath(Context cont,String[] pathes)
{
    OnScanCompletedListener callback=new OnScanCompletedListener() {


            public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
            //the work which want to do when scan completed
            }
        };
      MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(cont, paths, mimeTypes, callback);

}
```

we need only context and a string array from pathes which decide to scann those.
I write this method in a java calss.and becuse scanFile method need to a context so I passed it to method.
i wish this helped you.